# How to avoid duplicate rows in two tables without distinct in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: Example tables]

I am having a hard time understanding the concepts of join when there are extra level of details on second table. I have two tables as shown here, table 1 and table 2.

Let's say I want to return the `DOB` from table 2 alongside data from table 1:

```
select 
    t1.PERSON ID,
    t1.Celeb First Name,
    t1.Celeb Last Name,
    t2.DOB
from
    table 1 as t1
left join 
    table 2 t2 on t1.personid = t2.personid
```

I get duplicate rows even when I do a group by. What is the solution to only return one row? I don't want to use distinct as that slows my query a lot.

```
select 
    t1.PERSON ID,
    t1.Celeb First Name,
    t1.Celeb Last Name,
    t2.DOB
from 
    table 1 as t1
left join 
    table 2 t2 on t1.personid = t2.personid
group by
    t1.PERSON ID,
    t1.Celeb First Name,
    t1.Celeb Last Name,
    t2.DOB
```

Comment: Your query is not doing any aggregation, sample data as text please. Just FYI, it's Brad *Pitt*, Mark *Wahlberg*

Comment: Why would GROUP BY be faster? KISS.

Comment: Your data does not follow the normalization rules. The DOB is a property of Table1, but you placed it in Table2. That's a design issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting more than one row per person because there is more than one value for DOB according to your data; Person 1 having a DOB of '1/1/2020' and NULL. You could filter out these rows with the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE DOB IS NOT NULL
```

This will cause problems if you wanted to use the [MOVIE ACCESS] later though.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the aggregation functions like `max()` or `min()` to retrieve just one row, in your case you will need to use `max()` :

```
select 
    t1.PERSON ID,
    t1.Celeb First Name,
    t1.Celeb Last Name,
    max(t2.DOB)
from 
    table 1 as t1
left join 
    table 2 t2 on t1.personid = t2.personid
group by
    t1.PERSON ID,
    t1.Celeb First Name,
    t1.Celeb Last Name
```